# PHP mailer doesn't work in HTML format

Tags: php, html, email

I'm using a pretty standard e-mail creating function which I've used before, but it doesn't work for some reason I can't figure out. It sends a blank e-mail no matter what content I put inside it.

```
function sendToUser($email,$admin_email,$subject,$content){
    $to=$email;

    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
    $headers = "From: Site Name <$admin_email>";
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $admin_email";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\""; 
    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
    ?>
    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    <?php echo $content; ?>

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
    <?
    //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Now, if I call it like this:

```
sendToUser("myprivatemail@yahoo.com","admin@site.com","Testing","E-mail content");
```

It sends the e-mail, but it arrives empty. Does anyone see what's wrong here? Or could it be some server setting I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: what are the contents of `$message` if you `var_dump` it before you call the mail() function?

Comment: `--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash;` cannot have whitespace before it.

Comment: @Matt It doesn't, I checked just now.

Comment: making mail headers is painful. Why won't you use PHPMailer?

Comment: @robert According to the code you posted, yes it does. I had the same problem myself once; this was the solution.

Comment: @Stu Here's the var_dump: string(185) " --PHP-alt-c4789df29e613fa86b723097059ba159 
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 E-mail content
 --PHP-alt-c4789df29e613fa86b723097059ba159--
 "

Comment: @Matt There are no tabs or white spaces or anything in the original code, Stack Overflow formatted it this way.

Comment: Can you format it the *exact* way you have it in your script?

Comment: looks like there's whitespace at the beginning and end of the flush, not sure if that's a formatting thing here, or if it's happening in the php?

Comment: If it has worked before, what has changed? Maybe your platform? Operating system? sendmail app? sendmail app version?

Comment: The hosting hanged. But I just tested on the domain that it worked on before, and it doesn't. I am stumped by this, the code hasn't changed at all.

Comment: Why are you using `sendToUser` instead of directly using `mail()`? The way I see it you do not seem to be sending multipart emails.. because you are only have `text/plain` segment defined in the email

Comment: Because how am I gonna format the e-mail HTML content if I used mail() directly? The actual e-mails I want to send contain images and paragraphs of text, not just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

`--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash;` cannot have whitespace before it.

Try this:

```
function sendToUser($email,$admin_email,$subject,$content){
    $to=$email;

    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
    $headers = "From: Site Name <$admin_email>";
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $admin_email";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\""; 
    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
    ?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $content; ?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
    <?
    //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Does the result of `var_dump($message)` which I posted above help at all?

Comment: @robert Not unless it was wrapped in `<pre>` tags - web browsers tend to strip multiple whitespace characters.

Comment: BTW, the `var_dump()` makes it seem that there *are* whitespaces before your output.

Comment: But I'm looking at it now and there aren't, is there such a thing as an invisible whitespace? I even tried re-typing the whole function manually and the same problem remains.

Comment: If it's not the whitespace, I would have to take another look, but the code looks good to me.

Comment: If I change the Content-Type to "text/html" it sends the text in the test e-mail. However, if I try that with an actual e-mail (which contains images and styled HTML) it just sends the plain text.

Comment: Try including both. I usually reference http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look later, gotta run now.